# android tools preview channel

Tags: android, sdk

I have smtn that s driving me nuts in here,
I have Android SDK, Eclipse juno, win 64 and I have this ***tools (preview channel)***
that is showed as not installed, when am trying to install it, then are the "android sdk platform tools" and the sdk Tools (the are uppon this ) uninstelled, so I would like to either install botth or just delete this preview channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot install both at the same time. To disable the preview channel open the SDK Manager, select Tools -> Options from the menu and uncheck the "Enable Preview Tools" box.